# Como saber se um elemento foi clicado usando Javascript puro

Tags: javascript, html

Como saber se um descendente de um `<li>` foi clicado usando Javascript puro.

```
<div id="list">
    <a href="#">one</a>
    <a href="#">two</a>
    <a href="#">three</a>    
</div>
```

Usando Jquery seria:

```
$('#list a')
```

Como fazer usando Javascript puro?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

À semelhança do seu seletor com jQuery pode usar o [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) e ir buscar todos os elementos que são descendentes de `<li>` e usar um `for` loop para iterálos e amarrar um event handler a cada um.

Exemplo ([**live aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Bht/)):

```
var descendentes = document.querySelectorAll("#list a");
for (var i = 0; i < descendentes.length; i++) {
    descendentes[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        alert('O elemento clicado foi o ' + this.innerHTML);
    })
}
```

---

Uma outra opção é adicionar um click handler (para detectar o evento clique) sobre o `<li>` directamente. Se depois quiser saber qual o elemento descendente de `<li>` que foi clicado pode usar `event.target`.

Exemplo ([**live aqui**](http://jsfiddle.net/p3Bht/1/)):

```
var li = document.getElementById("list");
li.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    console.log(event.target); // este é o elemento clicado
    alert('O elemento clicado foi o ' + e.target.innerHTML);

    // dentro desta função o "this" refere-se ao <li>
})
```

Answer (score 2):

Utilize o [`document.getElementsByTagName()`](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_doc_getelementsbytagname.asp).

Comment: Robson, bemvindo ao Stackoverflow! Pode completar a sua resposta com exemplo de código para esta pergunta? Assim como está a resposta é pouco clara, para alem disso o link que juntou vai para uma página em Inglês o que não ajuda a quem não fale inglês.

Answer (score 2):

Se você pegar vários `div` com `document.getElementByTagName()`, depois você cria um `for` para adicionar a cada elemento um evento de clique com o `addEventListener()`. O elemento clicado vai ser referenciado ao objeto `this`, o qual você vai fazer a ação desejada.

Exemplo:

```js
 window.onload = function() {
 var divs = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
 
 for(var i=0; i<divs.length; i++) {
  divs[i].addEventListener("click", function() {
   this.style.backgroundColor = "#ccc";
   });
  }
 }
```

```css
div { width:100px; height:100px; background-color:#C00; margin:10px; display:inline-block;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Documento sem título</title>
  
</head>
  
<body>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
  <div></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Uma outra coisa que resolve e acredito que seja mais simples seria:

```
$("#list a").click(function(event){
     event.preventDefault(); //Essa linha vc coloca caso queira anular o evento do click da tag <a>;
     console.log("O elemento clicado foi: " + $(this).text();
});
```

Espero ter ajudado.
Boa sorte!

Comment: Na verdade a pergunta era sobre - como se fazer isso utilizando puro Javascript, mas isto não deixa de ser uma boa resposta, caso a intenção da pergunta fosse - como se fazer isso utilizando jQuery.

Comment: Tens razão, fui logo vendo e respondendo sem atentar para o restante da pergunta, obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Uma maneira concisa de se obter o elemento clicado é primeiro armazenar e obter a referência do elemento e depois adicionar um evento de escuta no elemento, e como argumento da função, usar o objeto event que disponibiliza várias propriedades, entre elas a propriedade **target**

```
const element = document.querySelector('element)

element.addEventListener('click', event => {
    console.log(event.target)
})
```

OBS: o target contem várias outras propriedades que também podem ser encadeadas para vários propósitos.